How to add a folder or file to root directory of an installed msi app?
I am using electron-forge with the maker maker-wix to create a MSI. It works fine.
When installed I have under C:/ProgramFiles the following structure:

MyApp/

app-1.0.0
App.exe
.installInfo.json



I would like to add here a folder called 'license' with file license.pdf.
But extraResource of packagerConfig adds it within app-1.0.0.
How can I add my file or folder to the root of the installed msi app?
I have tried using extraResource and looked into the hooks, but I'm confused which hook to use and when. AfterCopy seemed to do nothing at all.
